# How do I split an image to multiple images of the same height?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a screenshot with buttons in them:

[image]

**EDIT: I changed the image as the previous one produced an expected result.**

The height of each button is 48px (44px is the actual button, 4px is the bottom spacing). How can I:

1. trim the screenshot
2. split it vertically
3. trim the resulting image

I would like to be able to do all that in a single command.

This is what I tried for the 2. step:

```
convert -crop x48 +repage screenshot.png button%01d.png
```

But the first button was for some reason cropped at `37px`, shifting all the other screenshots, so I ended up with screenshots of 2 parts of 2 different buttons.

Why wasn't it cropped at `48px`?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** for the new image:

The image above has defined

```
$ exiftool-5.12 -a -u Flip9.png |grep -i offset
Image Offset                    : 17, 11 (pixels)
```

so you should use the next command for correctly setup the position of 1st page

```
convert -crop x48 -page +0+0 +repage Flip9.png menu%02d.png
```

With the above command you will got correct 9 images, like this one

[image]

more about the image offset here: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.10

Comment: Whoa... You're right, everything works as expected with that image. I've been trying to reproduce the error, but I can't, so I attached the original image instead of the previous one. Try now, it should produce the result I described.